# Send a part of webpage through email in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to send a part of webpage through email. Code is as follows:

```js
var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById("colMain").html());

window.location.href = link;
```

The `id` of the main div in the page is `colMain` which consists of the data to be sent in the mail. But the above code is not working having issue in the "body".

Can any body please come up with a solution?

Comment: What is `.html()` in `document.getElementById("colMain").html()` ?

Comment: Roko is right the `html()` function is only available if you use it it combination with jQuery.

Comment: Also `.escape()` is deprecated in favor of encodeURI or encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is here: `document.getElementById("colMain").html()`. `.html()` is a jQuery method and can only be applied on a `jQuery Object`.

`document.getElementById("colMain")` returns a (reference to a) node from the DOM, on which you can only apply [default methods and retrieve default properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Use `document.getElementById("colMain").innerHTML` to get the contents.

So, `jQuery` is not even required. If you want to use `jQuery` you have to convert the basic `DOM Element` to a `jQuery` object, or simply use the `jQuery` selectors:

`$("#colMain").html();`